# Batch File: How can I have a function return a value when the parameter passed to that function contains spaces?

Tags: windows, batch-file, spaces

I will try to explain as clearly as possible.  My scenario starts with a txt file, cases.txt, that contains two lines:

```
line1 () CASE1
line2 () CASE 2
```

The batch file iterates through that file using a FOR loop and passes each line to a function, find_index, that extracts (and should return) the location of the ')' character.  Here is the code that I can't get working:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (cases.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%a
    CALL :find_index %%a INDEX
    ECHO Found index at !INDEX!
)
GOTO :EOF

:find_index
    set S=%*
    set I=0
    set L=-1
    :l
        if "!S:~%I%,1!"=="" goto ld
        if "!S:~%I%,1!"==")" set L=%I%
        set /a I+=1
        goto l
    :ld
        SET %2 = %L%
        ECHO %2
        GOTO :EOF
```

What I want to happen is that the "INDEX" being passed to the function gets assigned the value of the result which I can then use for further operations (which I have yet to script because I'm stuck).  What happens is that %2 gets assigned with the value of the second word in the string () which being passed as a parameter to the function.  Sample output is:

```
line1 () CASE1
()
Index is at
line2 () CASE 2
()
Index is at
```

Expected output is for `ECHO %2` to return `7` and for the final output to read `Index is at 7`

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, from the very beginning to the end the variable !INDEX! is not defined anywhere. Your index value is actually being stored in the variable `!L!` and you don't need that function `:ld`. See below modified script and sample output.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (cases.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%a
    CALL :find_index %%a INDEX
    ECHO Found index at !L!
)
GOTO :EOF

:find_index
    set S=%*
    set I=0
    set L=-1
    :l
        if "!S:~%I%,1!"=="" goto :EOF
        if "!S:~%I%,1!"==")" set L=%I%
        set /a I+=1
        goto l
        GOTO :EOF
```

Tested output -

```
D:\Scripts>type cases.txt
line1 () CASE1
line2 () CASE 2
sometext () case3
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>draft.bat
line1 () CASE1
Found index at 7
line2 () CASE 2
Found index at 7
sometext () case3
Found index at 10
```

Cheers, G