# batch .cmd: Can I overwrite the parameter value %~1 and return it on a function?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm currently running a batch script to search through multiple different files for matching strings.
When string **A(foobar)** matches **B+C(foo+bar)**, then user is prompted to enter **D(qux)**, replacing **A** with **B+D(foo+qux)**.

During the search, the file will encounter multiple places where the script will replace the same A multiple times, but I don't want to prompt the user every time, only the first encounter.

Attempting at creating a dynamic function, I've supplied my function with 4 different parameters:

> B (First part of string): **foo**
>
> C (Second part of string, getting replaced): **bar**
>
> X (File location): **C:\application.properties**
>
> Y (Old stored B+D): **fooqux**

**Y** is essentially only supplied as parameter in order for the function to know which variable to overwrite (in my code: **batchIp** and **globalUnitName**)

[Batch File: How can I have a function return a value when the parameter passed to that function contains spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563093/batch-file-how-can-i-have-a-function-return-a-value-when-the-parameter-passed-t)
Shows that:

```
SET %2 = %L%
```

should be possible.

https://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php
Shows that:

```
set "%~1=DosTips"
```

should be possible.

My code:

```
:replace_properties
    set batchIp =
    call :replace_string "batch.ip=http://" "192.168.68.132" C:\application.properties %batchIp%
    call :replace_string "batch_ip = " "192.168.68.132" C:\processor.cfg %batchIp%
    set globalUnitName =
    call :replace_string "unit.name=" "Global_Default" C:\application.properties %globalUnitName%

:replace_string
    @echo off
    findstr /m "%~1%~2" %~3 >nul 2>nul
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        if "%~4"=="" (
            echo File: %~3
            echo   %~1%~2 was found, define new replacement:
            set /p applicationProperty="? %~1"
            IF NOT DEFINED applicationProperty SET "applicationProperty=%~2"
            echo before: %~4
            echo before: %batchIp%
            echo before: %globalUnitName%
            set %~4=!applicationProperty!
            echo after: %~4
            echo after: %batchIp%
            echo after: %globalUnitName%
        ) else (
            set applicationProperty="%~4"
        )
        powershell -Command "(gc %~3) -replace '%~1%~2' , '%~1!applicationProperty!' | Set-Content %~3"
        set applicationProperty=
    )
    exit /B 0
```

I would expect that the variable *batchIp* inside *:replace_properties* would be replaced with the content of *applicationProperty* inside *:replace_string* when running *set %~4=!applicationProperty!*.

However,

```
echo before: %~4
echo before: %batchIp%
echo before: %globalUnitName%
set %~4=!applicationProperty!
echo after: %~4
echo after: %batchIp%
echo after: %globalUnitName%
```

turns into:

> before:
>
> before:
>
> before:
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> after:
>
> after:
>
> after:

Comment: You can't do it this way. `%<number>` variables are created "by value", not "by reference".

Comment: No you cannot do that. By setting `set %~1=something` you actually set the variable name of `%~1` and not change the actual value. in other words if I do `set %~1=Test` then `echo %str%` in a batch file and then run `myfile.bat str` it will echo `Test` because we set a variable and value of `str=Test`

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) when you want to write *and* read variables in the same block of code; otherwise you will get their values *before* the whole block executes. Argument references `%1`etc. cannot be written but read only: if you try to do `set %1=value` you actually set a variable named like the first argument to the value...

Comment: Please at first read about [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) and change your code accordingly. Then describe your remaining issue(s).

Comment: An additional issue that I can see is that you should set variables with the format `set "var=value"`.

Comment: When plaing spaces around the equal sign in a set command they become part of the variable name and the content. Also called subroutines should be seperated from normal program flow with a prior `Goto :Eof` or `Exit /b`